# Django Template Form Fields show in a Disorder way

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on Django Form so basically I have four form fields like:

```
First Name:
Last Name:
Address:
Contact Info:
```

this form data came into Django Template and Render but display these field not in proper order. Every time I refresh page form field order changes.
Example: 
On first page load its like

```
Last Name: 
First Name:
Contact Info:
Address:
```

On Refreshing the page order changes like

```
Address:
Last Name:
Contact Info:
First Name:
```

here is my Django template form code which render the form in Tempalte:

```
{% for fields in formset %}
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <label class="col-4 control-label">{{fields.label}}
      </label>
     {{fields}}
   </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My Form.py File contain this Form:

```
class my_info(forms.Form):
    Action = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="First Name",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    choices=Action_choice)

    model_id = forms.CharField(
        label ='Last Name',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'hidden'})
    )

    Address = forms.CharField(
        label ='Address',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    ) ,

    Label = forms.CharField(
        label ='Contact Info',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
```

But I want to Display these fields in proper Order.

```
First Name:
Last Name:
Address:
Contact Info:
```

Comment: Can you share your `Form` code? Since attributes are not ordered in Python-2.7 (well these are stored in a dictionary, and that is not ordered), one has to specify the order explicitly.

Comment: Updated question with Form code. and can you please describe a bit how to specify the order. Actually when rendering the form it render in complete order but when it display on page order change

Comment: what Django version are you using?

Comment: I am using Django version 1.11.10 and python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You may check the django forms documentation for your specific version of django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

You can access each of the fields individually and render manually by using

```
{{ form.field }}}
```

in your template, instead of iterating over the formset you'll get them in the order you want:

```
<form method="get">
  {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-4 control-label"> {{ form.Action.label }}               
                </label>
                {{ form.Action }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-4 control-label"> {{ form.model_id.label }}               
                </label>
                {{ form.model_id }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-4 control-label"> {{ form.Address.label }}               
                </label>
                {{ form.Address }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="col-4 control-label"> {{ form.Label.label }}               
                </label>
                {{ form.Label }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Submit
        </button>
</form>
```

Also I would advise you to use more representative names for your form fields...

Answer (score 0):

In your **'meta'** class inside forms.py you might have set the fields in { }.
Curly braces is used for **set** which is disordered. 
Setting the field option in [ ] or ( ) help you to get it in the order you desire.

for eg:

```
`class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
      username = forms.CharField(help_text='')
      password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
      class Meta:
            model = UserRegistration
            fields = ['username','password']`
```